# jQuery: limit text string in link to different values depending on link count

Tags: jquery

I have a one-line list of (nine) flexboxed links, some (five) of which are marked by the `.cstlnk` class to indicate that they are customizable by the end user. Based on a `max-device-width: 767px` mobile display (e.g. Galaxy Note 8), I know I can distribute ~20 characters between them to keep all nine links looking pretty (e.g. spaces between separate links), and have the following jQuery function written as if the end user WILL use all five custom links. How can I most succinctly modify it so that each link will have more characters if fewer than five custom links are used? (I figure I could write all the separate if statements, but that would take a lot of lines.)

Thanks!

```js
// for reference, this is based off the text-function answer on question#24200493
// the html-function answer didn't work for me
$(".links .cstlnk").text(function(i, currentText) {
    return $(this).text().substring(0,4)
});
```

```css
.infotxt {width:90%; padding:1em; background:#eee;}
.infotxt.links {
    list-style:none;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="infotxt links">
  <li id="ask">ask</li>
  <li id="sub">submit</li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">1longstring1</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">2longstring2</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">3longstring3</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">4longstring4</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">5longstring5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">dash</a></li>
  <li><a href="">thm</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, this is what ended up working for me. Since I know the maximum allowed characters (per custom-link, for a "comfortable" separation), I defined two constants (number of custom links ID'ed with `.cstlink`, and a division equation of max total allowed characters divided by number of links); and **set `substring` to go up to the latter constant instead of 4**. Notice how commenting out two of five `.cstlnk` elements results in the remaining three displaying a longer string compared to the snippet in my question post. (As in CharlietFL's answer, I increased the matchMedia width for demo purposes.)

A five-second test would seem to indicate that simply changing that 4 to a division equation, without defining either of those constants, is a valid solution as well. Both versions are shown in the below snippet.

```js
$(function(){
  let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-device-width: 1600px)").matches;
  if (isMobile) {
    const numLinks = $(".links .cstlnk").length,
    trimChar = 20 / numLinks;
    $(".links .cstlnk").text(function(i, currentText) {
      return $(this).text().substring(0,trimChar) // uses above-defined constants
      // OR
      return $(this).text().substring(0, 20 / $(".links .cstlnk").length) // without constants
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.infotxt {width:90%; padding:1em; background:#eee;}
.infotxt.links {
    list-style:none;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="infotxt links">
  <li id="ask">ask</li>
  <li id="sub">submit</li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">1longstring1</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">2longstring2</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">3longstring3</a></li>
  <!--<li class="cstlnk"><a href="">4longstring4</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">5longstring5</a></li>-->
  <li><a href="">dash</a></li>
  <li><a href="">thm</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object using number of links as keys and number of characters as values then lookup the character count based on length of link elements

Following is loosely developed and probably needs more logic applied to meet your needs but should give you a good basic start point. I set the matchMedia width to larger value than your requirements just for demo purpose

```js
const linkChars = {
  5: 6, // dummy values
  4: 7,
  3: 10
}

if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1600px)')) {

  const $cstlinks = $(".links .cstlnk"),
    numLinks = $cstlinks.length,
    numChars = linkChars[numLinks];

  if (numLinks < 6) {
    $(".links .cstlnk").text(function(i, currentText) {
      return currentText.substring(0, numChars - 1)
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.infotxt {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #eee;
}

.infotxt.links {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="infotxt links">
  <li id="ask">ask</li>
  <li id="sub">submit</li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">1longstring1</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">2longstring2</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">3longstring3</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">4longstring4</a></li>
  <li class="cstlnk"><a href="">5longstring5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">dash</a></li>
  <li><a href="">thm</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Plopping the jQuery into my site predictably doesn't work, but I'm afraid I can't quite mentally translate it and know what part(s) to modify to make it work. What you wrote for `linkChars` and `numChars` is very new to me; I'm having some trouble looking up more on it.

Comment: is same as doing `let obj ={'a':1); console.log(obj['a'])// returns 1`

Answer (score 0):

[ width 100% / li length ] with [ max-width & overflow hidden ] is solution

```js
function resetList() {
  let li = $('.list li');
  console.log(li.length);
  
  li.each(function () {
    $(this).css('max-width', $(this).parent('.list').width() / li.length);
  });
}
resetList();
$(window).on('resize',  resetList);
```

```css
.list {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.list li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">ask</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">submit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1longstring1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2longstring2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3longstring3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4longstring4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5longstring5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">dash</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">thm</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: At the time of this writing, I haven't tried either proposed solution, but now I wonder if that window resize line could allow for dynamic switching between desktop and mobile displays if a desktop user resizes their window. Somehow I suspect the answer is no.